# awk command to change field seperator from tilde to tab

Tags: awk

I want to replace the delimter tilde into tab space in awk command, I have mentioned below how I would have expect.

input

```
~1~2~3~
```

Output

```
	1	2	3
```

this wont work for me

```
awk -F"~" '{ OFS ="\t"; print }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 7):

It's really a job for tr:

```
tr '~' '\t'
```

but in awk you just need to force the record to be recompiled by assigning one of the fields to its own value:

```
awk -F'~' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk NF=NF FS='~' OFS='\t'
```

Result

```
	1	2	3
```

Comment: i am Getting error used the above cmd, awk : syntax error near line number 1.

Comment: This does not work with all awk.  '$1=$1' would be more portable.  Also, this will suppress output of blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$echo ~1~2~3~|sed 'y/~/\t/'
    1       2       3
```

Comment: sed not works for me but i got the output using perl  Thanks for all your help . perl -pe 's/~/\t/g' inputfile

Comment: @user2449709 you might have better luck using [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) -- `sed $'y/~/\t'`